# 2021 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

MathOverflow's [second moderator election](https://mathoverflow.net/election/2) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the three new moderators are:

[image: Asaf Karagila] [image: Tim Campion] [image: Stefan Kohl]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://mathoverflow.net/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://mathoverflow.net/election/2), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/6244107849564160).

Comment: Congratulations!! I for one welcome our new overlords.

Answer (score 39):

On behalf of the moderator team and the whole community, I would like to congratulate you and officially welcome you to the team!

Comment: I must say now that the election is over:  I was very impressed by all the candidates, and this group of three will really be re-energizing.